# DNS address not acquired by ubuntu

Tags: linux, networking, dns, ubuntu-12.04

I have a lenovo G430 machine with ubuntu 12.04 running on it. The Network configuration is DHCP, It gets the IP but fails to get the DNS and henceforth wont be able to browse internet.The issue is only with this machine as all the other machine's in the network is able to connect and browse fine.

Comment: How do you set up your network connection? Do you use some application like "networkmanager" or "wicd"? If so, are you sure that it is set to get DNS server address automatically and not just the IP address?

Comment: @AcId I use a networkmanager for managing the connections. How do i set it to receive dns ? i have just given the DHCP in network settings.

Comment: In _networkmanager_, when you edit the connection, under the _IPv4 Settings_ tab, the method should be `Automatic(DHCP)` and **NOT** `Automatic(DHCP) addresses only`. If this is allready the case, I don't know why it doesn't get DNS info, when it works for other PCs on the same network. You could try and set some DNS server manually e.g. (8.8.8.8) and (8.8.4.4) for Google DNS.

Comment: If the connection i wired, you could also try setting up the connection manually with _ifconfig_. If you're network controller is named _eth0_: First disable networkmanager, then, as root run `ifconfig eth0 up` followed by `dhcpcd eth0`, and see if this makes any difference. It gets a bit more compicated with a wireless interface, because you have to associate with the AP first.

Comment: @AcId Its already on Automatic(DHCP) as you have mentioned. and if i have to set manually, that is a pain setting it manually every day.     Anyways thank you for the inputs.

Comment: In _networkmanager_ you can set IP settings for each network. So if you add DNS servers manually to your network configuration, it should be saved for each time you log on to the same network. It is still not optimal, but at least you can get DNS resolution to work. Also, have you updated _networkmanager_, _kernel_ etc. to the latest versions?